# Editing CSV file with Bash Script

Tags: bash, csv, command-line

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
English, "Hawkin, Jason" ,JHAWKIN110@exampleemail.com
English, "McDonald, Matt" ,MMCDONALD114@exampleemail.com
English, "Campbell, Josh" ,JCAMPBELL111@exampleemail.com
```

My intention is to make a Bash Script to make a second CSV file with the following format:

```
ID, Email, FNAME, LNAME
jhawkin110, JHAWKIN110@exampleemail.com, Jason, Hawkin
```

After using "cut" to remove the first column I did not need, I am at a loss on how to create the "ID" by extracting the first part of the "Email".

Comment: Forget the cut and check out awk.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: What's your field separator? Comma, comma followed by one space or one space followed by comma?

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","; print "ID, Email, FNAME, LNAME"}{gsub(/"/,"");split($NF,a,"@"); print tolower(a[1])," " $NF, $3, $2}' input_file
ID, Email, FNAME, LNAME
jhawkin110, JHAWKIN110@exampleemail.com, Jason , Hawkin
mmcdonald114, MMCDONALD114@exampleemail.com, Matt , McDonald
jcampbell111, JCAMPBELL111@exampleemail.com, Josh , Campbell
```

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/.*"([^,]*),([^"]*)..,(([^@]*)@.*)/\3,\2, \1,\L\4/;s/(.*),(.*)/\2, \1/;1iID, Email, FNAME, LNAME' input_file
ID, Email, FNAME, LNAME
jhawkin110, JHAWKIN110@exampleemail.com, Jason, Hawkin
mmcdonald114, MMCDONALD114@exampleemail.com, Matt, McDonald
jcampbell111, JCAMPBELL111@exampleemail.com, Josh, Campbell
```